# Wicket: Submit button to download binary file

Tags: wicket

I know how to create a plain link to download arbitrary binary data (using `ResourceLink` with `ResourceStreamResource` and `AbstractResourceStream`), but now I want to create a form whose submit button should either redirect to the form again (e.g. to correct an input error) or to download an arbitrary binary data file without going to a different page. How this can be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the binary part, try something like this:

```
final ResourceStreamRequestHandler target = new ResourceStreamRequestHandler(new AbstractResourceStream() {
    @Override
    public String getContentType() {
        return "application/octet-stream";
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream getInputStream() throws ResourceStreamNotFoundException {
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(yourBinaryContent);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
    }
});
target.setFileName("response.dat");
target.setContentDisposition(ContentDisposition.ATTACHMENT);

getRequestCycle().scheduleRequestHandlerAfterCurrent(target);
```

Otherwise, to handle 'text' responses, use the code you already have.